# tycho-p2-director-plugin materialize-products execution fails because wants a directory but was .jar

Tags: maven, maven-3, tycho

I try to build a product with Tycho 0.13.0, but I get a following error while materialize-product execute:

> An error occurred while installing the items  session context
>   was:(profile=DefaultProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install,
>   operand=null --> [R]org.jruby 1.2.0,
>   action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.eclipse.actions.ChmodAction).
>   The artifact
>   ${PATH_TO_PRODUCT_PLUGIN}/target/products/ewa/linux/gtk/x86/plugins/org.jruby_1.2.0.jar is not a directory.

And the following error after Reactor summary:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-p2-director-plugin:0.13.0:materialize-products
>   (materialize-products) on project org.ewazone.ewa.project: P2 director
>   return code was 13 -> [Help 1]

`pom.xml` in a project plugin:

```
<parent>
        <artifactId>ewa</artifactId>
        <groupId>ewa.ewa</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>ewa</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.ewazone.ewa.project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0.qualifier</version>
    <packaging>eclipse-repository</packaging>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-p2-director-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho-version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>materialize-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>materialize-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>archive-products</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>archive-products</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have no ideas about how to solve that problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go into the `org.jruby` plugin's manifest file, you can add the `Eclipse-BundleShape: dir` line (Case Sensitive) and it will then pop out as a directory in your product's plugins folder.